# xQuery Inserting Nodes syntax

Tags: xquery, xmlspy

I'm using XMLSpy.
I'm trying to do a simple xquery **insert** into an XML document where I insert a node into preexisting node(s);

```
xquery version "3.0";
declare namespace ext="http://www.altova.com/xslt-extensions";

let $mydoc := doc("MyData.xml")
let $ssn := <SSN>999-99-9999</SSN>

for $n in $mydoc//Account
return  insert node $ssn into $n
```

I receieve syntax error *XPST0003: The expression around 'return insert node $ssn into $n' is not a valid instance of the XQuery grammar*

So "insert" (or delete, or update) are flagged as incorrect grammar.  Is there an extension I'm missing?

Performing queries without those keyword is working -i.e. general xquery expressions working.

Can someone direct me to what may be wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [latest version](http://www.altova.com/whatsnew.html) of XMLSpy was just released and it supports the [XQuery Update Facility](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-update-10/), which is not a part of standard XQuery.

Comment: So I should be able to run this outside of XMLSpy with any XSLT processor like saxon?